# I have one functionality that i want to add in single.php page using function in custom plugin. how can i?

Tags: php, wordpress

*I have this code that I want to add in **single.php** using a custom plugin.*

**here is the code:**

```
<?php
echo "Facebook: ". $facebook_like_share_count ("$url"). "<br>";
echo "Pinterest: ". $pinterest_pins ("$url") . "<br>";
echo "Google+: ". $google_plusones ("$url") . "<br>";
?>
```

I want to print this things in **single.php** when install my custom plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two options possible.

Option 1) Create a short code

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
   echo "Facebook: ". $facebook_like_share_count ("$url"). "<br>";
   echo "Pinterest: ". $pinterest_pins ("$url") . "<br>";
   echo "Google+: ". $google_plusones ("$url") . "<br>";

}
add_shortcode( 'social', array( &$this, 'bartag_func' ));
```

Your short code with be [social]

Option 2 ) Apply the filter on the content

```
/**
 * summary
 */
class WP_Custom_Data 
{
    /**
     * summary
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
         //Here you can add for shortcode as well
         add_filter('the_content', array($this, 'wpdev_before_after'));

    }
    public function wpdev_before_after($content) {

        $url = "xyzurl"; 
        $api = file_get_contents( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . $url ); 
        $count = json_decode( $api ); 
        $beforecontent = $count->share->share_count;
        $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content;
        return $fullcontent;
    }
    // here you can call the shortcode function as well
}
$wpspw_pro_script = new WP_Custom_Data();
```

Note : I am not sure what you are doing here with function because you have set the variable as a function. according to me it must give you the error.

Anyways, according to me there two option possible here and i have given you the options for same

Comment: Actually i am creating plugin,
i have added another code in functions.php directly and its works.

here its for facebook.


`$url = "xyzurl";


$facebook_like_share_count = function ( $url ) {



    $api = file_get_contents( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . $url );



    $count = json_decode( $api );



    return $count->share->share_count;


};`

Comment: Yes my code is for functions.php if you are creating the plugin than you need to cll the filter and shortcode into your constructor and than you need to define the function as a public function than this code will work

Comment: I did the sample code for you for the option 2 and you can apply your logic here